# need to send error to unauthorized user in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

as the title is obvoius i need to send back some error message for unauthorized user and i need to know how to achive this for example i need to send this message to user

> you dont have any username to begin chat

and print it in users browser how should i do that? the client side code is something like this

```
//this is the client side code
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost', { resource: '/chat/app.js' });

        // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
            socket.emit('adduser')
        });

    socket.socket.on('error', function (reason){
      console.log('Unable to connect Socket.IO', reason);
    });
```

but the reason which i get in console is

> Unable to connect Socket.IO handshake error

how should i print the message which is the cause of user is nothing get authorized?

this is the server side code

```
        var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

        io.configure(function (){
          io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
            // findDatabyip is an async example function
            findDatabyIP(handshakeData.address.address, function (err, data) {
              if (err) return callback(err);

              if (data.authorized) {
                handshakeData.foo = 'bar';
                for(var prop in data) handshakeData[prop] = data[prop];
                callback(null, true);
              } else {
//THIS IS THE MESSAGE *********************************************
                callback('you dont have any username to begin chat', false);
              }
            }) 
          });
        });
```

Comment: Do you still get that error when the date in the callback from findDatabyIP matches? In otherwords, do you always get this error, or only when your user isn't found in the findDatabyIP call?

Answer (score 0):

To send the error back to the user you must modify the error function on manager.js (socket.io\lib\manager.js; line 768 approx) from this

```
function error (err) {
    writeErr(500, 'handshake error');
    self.log.warn('handshake error ' + err);
  };
```

to this

```
function error (err) {
    writeErr(500, /*'handshake error'*/ err);
    self.log.warn('handshake error ' + err);
  };
```